# How to change the buffer size for streaming in android videoview?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

Good day. Can I change the buffer size in accepting the video for streaming? I'm using udp for streaming here's my sample code:

```
vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);      
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
vv.setMediaController(mc);
Uri video = Uri.parse("udp://@239.239.1.1:1234");
vv.setVideoURI(video);
vv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

 @Override
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  vv.start();
 }          

});
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. The buffersize is part of the firmware. You can only change the buffersize in the firmware.

Comment: Is it possible to patch this firmware?